# [AS3]memory Leak for compressed image loaded with Loader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, memory-leaks, adobe-scout

I am actually using the Loader Class to get an image from a distante server.
I am using it for is job and when it's done I remove it from memory but there is a little leak.

To see it, I am using scout. In the memory part, the Bitmap DisplayObjects is free but the Images part is not.

When I look at the scout documentation, I found that the Images part is the compressed version of the files I am loading.

What should I do to free this part of the memory?

thanks

edit 2(forget the _ before loader):
Here is what I did to free the Loader :

```
(_loader.content as Bitmap).bitmapData.dispose();
_loader.unload();
this.removeChild(_loader);
_loader = null;
```

edit 3 : 
I still need help for my memory leaks, thanks

Comment: You should add a code example. Also, do you remember to call dispose() on the BitmapData ?

Comment: If that's your actual code, you're simply missing an underscore: the last line should be `_loader=null;`

Comment: Sorry it's juste a mistake I made when copying my code. It's still not working as I expected.

Comment: Have you tried running a release build thru Scout to see if the leak persists?

Comment: I've tried in release and it the same.
Images is still growing

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to have a memory leak when using the Loader class.
For the garbage collector to remove an object from the memory following rules must apply:

- The object has no references
- The object has no event listeners (or the event listeners have a WeakReference set to true)
- The object is not included in any array

Here's a small example of using the Loader

```
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("url here");

var l:Loader = new Loader();
l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
l.load(urlReq);
```

Looks pretty simple, doesn't it? ;) I did not include the handler, since it's not important for this example.

Now let's remove it:

```
l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
//the LoaderInfo object is inside the Loader object, it needs to be free of listeners
//or it won't let the Loader object to be garbage collected

var content:DisplayObject = l.content; // save the loaded item
l = null; // make object NULL
```

Now the loader should be removed from the memory on the next garbage collector run. Just make sure you've cleared all the listeners and references.

Hope that helps!